# JSTree CSS settings

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4, jstree

In my project I use a JSTree inside a Bootstrap layout. Now I want to make the JSTree as 100% of the container it is placed into.  For this I use:

```
.container{
    max-width: 100% !important;
    width:100%;
}

.casetree{
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    overflow:scroll;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: lightgrey;
    border-radius: 2px;
}
```

But if I do this CSS style, the JSTree will change its size to its content not to the container it is placed in. Any suggestion why this happen?

The html where I use the jstree

```
<div class="container">
  <!-- Erste Reihe mit Optionen und Tree -->
  <div class="row">
   <!-- Linke Spalte -->
    <div class="col-8" style="margin:0px;padding:0px;" >
      <div id="myTree" class="casetree"></div>
    </div>
    <!-- /END Linke Spalte -->
    <!-- Rechte Spalte -->
    <div class="col-4">
        test
    </div>
    <!-- /END Rechte Spalte -->
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: Sccreenshot]

Comment: Can you show your HTML?

Comment: Updated the question with more info

Comment: Are `col-8` & `col-4` valid bootstrap classes? ... Also you can put your `id="myTree"` on the `div` above it. It doesn't have to be nested.